# Ошибка при чтении файла в libgdx с использованием "шринкера"

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx, proguard

Пишу игру на **libgdx** для **android** на **java**. Если в build gradle поставить `minifyEnabled true`, то приложение вылетает с ошибкой - не получается прочитать файл. Если проставить `minifyEnabled false`, то все работает, но приложение становится чуть тяжелее.

Помогите понять, что такое делает шринкер, из-за чего у меня не получается прочитать файл?

https://answer-id.com/ru/64512606 - данная статья была максимально близка к решению моей проблемы. Из-за нее я понял, что проблема в proguardPro. НО совет не помог(

Ниже стек с ошибкой:

```
2021-09-03 12:59:13.926 31979-32122/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
    Process: com.overlive, PID: 31979
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.h0: Error reading file: gameplay/game_data.json
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.p.a(Unknown Source:35)
        at com.overlive.b.a.y(Unknown Source:38)
        at com.overlive.b.a.x(Unknown Source:71)
        at com.overlive.c.c.c.x(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.overlive.c.c.c$a.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.h0: Field not found: chapters (com.overlive.a.c.b)
    Serialization trace:
    {}.chapters
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.p.a(Unknown Source:94)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.p.a(Unknown Source:434)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.p.a(Unknown Source:10)
            ... 5 more
```